# Cocos2d: Is there a way to change volume to CDSoundSource?

Tags: ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I am experimenting with CDSoundSource and caf files. Is there a way to set the volume as for background music? By using setGain I can put the volume to 0 but can't really adjust it.

For example:

```
CDSoundSource *sound = [soundSources objectForKey:fn];
    [sound setGain:0.0f]; 
    sound.looping = NO;
    [sound play];
```

Will mute the volume but the same code with a value of [sound setGain:0.1f] would not do much difference. I couldn't find a proper reference on this. Has anyone some suggestion?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Have you tried maybe 0.5? I think it might be a logarithmic scale

Comment: @Ben yes I tried but didn't make much differene.. hunting for the solution now :)